# Restrict number of record in mongoDb collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have mongoDb collection and it contains the records as shown 
    [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjR4g.png)

Requirement is that this collection should have at max 4 records for each 'ExternalId'.  
If collection has 4 records for 'ExternalId' 4 and i called insert operation to insert new record of 'ExternalId' 4 then i need to delete the existing forth record for 'ExternalId' 4 and keep the new one in Collection.

Is it possible through mongoDb feature 
If i have to do it programatically in nodes what is the best way i should pick

Answer (score 3):

You have a nice idea here, I suggest you to use `MongoDB` Capped collection 
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/

This is a circular collections the oldest document is removed and the latest is added in, this type of collection use at maximum the nature of hard disk to spin and usually are fast.

```
db.createCollection("log", { capped : true, size : 1024, max : 4 } )
```